# How do you program this UI to be compatible with all screen sizes?

Tags: user-interface, android

So, I want to develop de following UI, I developed using a RelativeLayout and then I put it the buttons using margins...

I have realised that this isn't a good way, if you need to develop this UI how you will do it? or what widgets you will use to develop this.

[image: The UI, it's on iphone, but I want to be the same in android]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into writing a custom view (extends View, overrides onDraw());

Or you should definitely make your assets into 9-patches.  This will give the graphics "stretchable" logic.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know about Android, and haven't had any probes with screen sizes, but this code might help you

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
          android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
          android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
          android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
          android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
          android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

I found it out [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html), check it out for more information.

Comment: I think that this only blocks the use of the application in the phones that no had the requisits that you put in the Manifest.